# Apache2 virtual host throwing this site cant be reached

Tags: apache, virtualhost, lamp

hi i am just a beginner to virtual host configuration in apache2 and followed tutorials about configuring virtual hosts but when i open the url it says this site cant me reached.
my config file in available sites is

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName anet2.ogmait.com
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

also i have run

```
  sudo a2ensite anet2.conf
```

which returns the site is enabled.Please guide me if i am doing wrong somewhere.Would be a great favor.
Thankyou

Comment: What is `a2ensite`?  Is that how they start httpd on ubuntu or something? Is apache even running? What OS are you using? Is there anything thing in the log files? What does `ps -ef | grep httpd` show? Why does your config have ` <IfModule mod_ssl.c>` on the first line?

Comment: yes apache is running. a2ensite is apache2 enable site to make available sites , enabled. I am using Ubuntu.I have check log files but nothing is showing.

Comment: ps -ef | grep httpd shows this
root      6229  6215  0 06:38 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd
and <IfModule mod_ssl.c> came with the default generated config

Comment: If httpd is running then maybe your system has a firewall set up.  What does `sudo iptables -L` output?

Comment: sudo iptables -L outputs 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: Did you restart apache2 after a2ensite?

Comment: yes i have restarted as well